# Azure's VM provisioning

Tags: c#, .net, azure, virtual-machine

Is there a way to programmatically manage the Azure Virtual Machines? I need to provision VM instances through a dotnet/C# program and do not want to deal with XML and powershell.

Also ability to Start/Stop/Delete/Provision instances would be useful.

Comment: Stackoverflow is for specific programming problems. I think you asked this in wrong place.

Comment: I think the question could be edited for clarity instead of downvoting it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the [Azure Fluent Management](http://fluentmanagement.elastacloud.com/iaas/) nuget package.

```
> Install-Package Elastacloud.AzureManagement.Fluent
```

This gives a dotnet wrapper to the service management REST api.